# ActionScript Flash: Change frame depending on JSON value

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I have a weather widget I'm making in flash that has seven frames for different weather types (eg. rain, snow, cloudy) and I'm using a JSON feed to get the data. The feed provides various different descriptions for similar weather conditions but instead of redirecting to each to a different frame I want to direct it to one that has a similar description for example 'light rain' and 'heavy drizzle' will direct to the 'rain' frame. The code below is what I have so far and it directs to different frames if it is the same name as the weather condition it retrieves which would involve needing a lot more frames than are needed. I was wondering if someone could suggest an addition to the code that will give me the desired navigation.
Thanks in advance.

```
stop();
function loadConfigFromUrl():void
{
    var urlRequest:URLRequest  = new URLRequest("http://api.wunderground.com/api/51e30dac841a0fbe/conditions/q/zmw:00000.1.03969.json");

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

    try{
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
    } catch (error:Error) {
        trace("Cannot load : " + error.message);
    }
}

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);   

    var data:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
    trace(data.current_observation.weather);
    trace(data.current_observation.temp_c);
    trace(data.current_observation.wind_kph);

    gotoAndStop(data.current_observation.weather)

    weather.text = data.current_observation.weather;
    temp.text = data.current_observation.temp_c + "°C";
    wind.text = data.current_observation.wind_kph + "km/h"
}
loadConfigFromUrl();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use a switch statement, ([AS3 Docs reference here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#switch)) so that multiple values can have the same output. Something like this:

```
var frameToUse:String;

switch(data.current_observation.weather)
{
    case "light rain":
    case "heavy drizzle":
    case "other rain type"
        frameToUse = "rainFrameLabel";
    break;
    case "sunny":
        frameToUse = "sunFrameLabel";
    break;
}

gotoAndStop(frameToUse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the perfect place for a **Multimap**. It allows you to map multiple values to a single key. In your case it would be:

- rain

  - light rain
  - heavy drizzle
  - storm

The unfortunate thing is that AS3 doesn't have this data structure built in. It's not hard to write but even better is that people out there have [already written it for you](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1322).